# How to get these image in my page in responsive for every device?

Tags: php, html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

[image: I want these images in my page to be responsive for every device. Please help wit div col thing.]

I want these images in my page to be responsive for every device. Please help wit div col thing.

Comment: you should add img{max-width:100%;}

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

add max-width for images. so it will take responsive for all devices

```
img{ 
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `width:100%` to adjust for all devices

```css
.foralldevices {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Responsive Image for every device</h2>

<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTgdmgiXDeDj7Osrvbdl1Ppuos_q_uCDIUZims8fBQjFzXwRoxX" alt="Nature" class="foralldevices">
</div>
```